# jquery conditional formating on negative number value

Tags: jquery

I was able to find a few examples and pieced things together to get this working.

```
$(".status").filter(function () {
    return (/\(\)/).test($(this).html());
})
    .closest(\'td\').css(\'background-color\', \'red\');
});
```

However, I need to take this further and evaluate the negative value for a scalable conditional format.

if value of td is positive backgrond-color should be green.
if value of td is negative which is representied in parantheses (###,###) then I want to evaluate based on these conditions.

```
(1) thru (199,999) =  .closest('td').css('background-color', 'yellow');

(200,000) or greater = .closest('td').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: Why are you escaping all the quotes?

Comment: the escaped quotes came out of an echo from PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.css()` accepts a function as the value parameter.

Here's one possible solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/JUJBj/

```
$(".status").filter(function () {
    return (/\(.+\)/).test($(this).html());
}).closest('td').css('background-color', function() {
    var val = parseInt($(this).find('.status').text().replace(/\(|\)/g, ''), 10);
    return val >= 200000 ? 'red' : 'yellow';
});
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted, but have a question.  Your example works with the <span> included, why is it that when the <span> is removed and class assigned to the <td> it only assigns yellow?

Comment: It's because of the `$(this).find('.status')` part. `this` is the `td`, and after your change, doesn't have a descendant with the class `status`, so the whole thing fails. Yellow is just the default. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ttaA2/